# ORCID API - how to get coauthor/collaborator information?

Tags: python, orcid

I am using the [ORCID Public API](https://info.orcid.org/documentation/features/public-api/) to get information about various authors publishing in scholarly journals. I want to know, can I get information about contributing authors on a publication? I cannot find anywhere in the documentation to address this.  I know this information is there. For example, if I search for an author and then a publication under that author, I see something like this:

[image]

All the co-authors are clearly listed under the "Contributors" section

For example I am making the following API call in python to get information about a particular author by their ORCID:

```
orcid_only = "0000-0002-1112-4522"

# URL for ORCID API
ORCID_RECORD_API = "https://pub.orcid.org/v3.0/"

# query ORCID for an ORCID record
response = requests.get(url=requests.utils.requote_uri(ORCID_RECORD_API + orcid_only),
headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})
response.raise_for_status()
result = response.json()
print(result)
```

Comment: Looks like once you know the ID of the work, you might need another call to a `/works` endpoint to get the data: https://github.com/ORCID/ORCID-Source/blob/main/orcid-api-web/tutorial/works.md#work-fields That should have a `work-contributors` element.